# Como exibir ou extrair toda informação "cookie" de uma pagina via python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, request

**Estou tentando extrair o cookie de uma pagina mas só consigo informações do NID:**

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://www.google.com/')
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
{'NID': '204=nKJSokAbELYYO54Rj-qPjZ_ES0MckXrTdA_1dHceNFIOEU6S9qxT1Tn8ROe5o2lB2JxToKXw1o48sn_a1c5KvY8H60U7ZjDVheg-Dl1ahy31HydxgOfUXeGeSUGvdwEmNd_kMk3CWcl3d2SQpw5Iu8flaA_yROToJfJDo0WshBE'}
```

**Como visualizar mais opções como o "DV", como faço isso?**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Atenção, o *cookie* **DV** indicado na sua pergunta está contido na requisição (*Request*), e não na resposta (*Response*)!

Alguns *cookies* podem ser gerados de forma dinâmica. Provavelmente, algum código `JavaScript` foi executado pelo navegador após o *download* do conteúdo da página, o que ocasionou na geração desses *cookies*.

A biblioteca Python `requests` não interpreta o conteúdo da página, ou seja, se houver algum código `JavaScript` nesse conteúdo, ele não será executado.

Uma solução alternativa é usar a biblioteca [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), que é capaz de [*escravizar*](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/Intro.html) um navegador (*driver*) para interpretar o conteúdo de uma determinada página, veja só:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
print(cookies)
driver.close()
```

Saída:

```
[
  {'name': 'NID', 'value': '204=sJ0qzKNZMg1bjKafu3ogygb9K9pjfRPhlhNZoJbJ_CRHN0ISwwcjgl47xBjcl3YSOyC0szfBI_XLbkvFlLOkUtzfpCqiD-NYHrOuwQFeKjgc18uNrDfZLby2FpWUuN29Shot10tQA7WBpY_TqWGQjejycOSsvl3mdILX3lM6Ydw', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.google.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': True, 'expiry': 1607022048},
  {'name': '1P_JAR', 'value': '2020-06-03-19', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.google.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1593802849}
]
```

Comment: Dessa maneira realmente gera todo o conteúdo, mas para usar sem a presença de um navegador(drive) não seria possível?